# Yodlee check whether user has already added account or not

Tags: ruby, validation, yodlee

I am integrating yodlee with one of my financial app.
I need to add validation whether user can add(i.e. link) his account only at one time.

Currently yodlee gives new siteAccountId everytime if user logins to same account again and again.

Is there any way to add this validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be using Site Based APIs for aggregation or Fastlink, then Yodlee takes care of this. Yodlee system will **not** generate new siteAccountId if user is adding the same site with same credentials, unless  either username or password is changed.